# "see something up close"

Tags: word-meaning

> Much of what Maccari put on the runway might actually have been better appreciated in a more intimate setting where audience members are able to put their hands on the fabric, **see the details up close** . But putting Perry Ellis on the runway during the inaugural season of New York Fashion Week: Men’s, served a larger purpose. It sent a message: This, too, is fashion. And there’s nothing to fear.

What is the difference between “see something closely” and “see something up close”?

Comment: [Up-close](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/up-close): In great detail, at very close range.

Comment: And we don't say see something closely; we say _look [at something] closely_ or _examine closely_. This means you are paying attention to details. Saying "see up close" just means you are positioned close to the thing you are looking at, it says nothing about how you are looking at it. You might be examining details, you might not.

Answer (score 1):

Closely is an adverb. It modifies the verb, if we were to switch "up close" with "[closely](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/closely)" it would modify the verb "see".

"[Up close](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/up-close)" can be used both as an adverb an adjective. Adjectives modify nouns, in this case it appears to be modifying the understood pronoun "they" - effectively saying:

> If they were up close, they could see the details of the fabric.

(On a personal note I feel like the example sentence is missing an "and" right before "see the details up close" but the way it is written now is correct I believe.)